# my login method is not being called within my register() and my error in mainError(0 comes up when it's not supposed to

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, error-handling

This is my code:

```
import time

print("Welcome to the quiz")

print("Would you like to login with an existing account or register for a new account?")

def login():
    userQ = input("Please enter your username: ")
    passQ = input("Please enter your password: ")
    #In progress of making...

def register():
    print ("Your username will now be created from your first name and age.")
    fname = input("Please enter your first name: ")
    age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    fname2 = fname[:3]
    username = fname2 + age
    print ("Your username is {}".format(username.upper()))
    password = input("Please enter a password for your new account: ")
    time.sleep(1.0)
    print ("Username: {}".format(username))
    print ("Password: {}".format(password))
    with open("UserPass.csv", "w") as f:
        for line in f:
            file = line.split(",")
            f.write(username) in file[0]
    print ("ACCOUNT CREATED")
    login()

class validation(Exception):

    def __init__(self, error):
        self.error = error

    def printError(self):
        print ("Error: {} ".format(self.error))

def mainError():
    try:
        raise validation('Please enter a valid input')
    except validation as e:
        e.printError()

def Menu():
    while True:
        options = ["Login", "Register"]
        print("Please, choose one of the following options")
        num_of_options = len(options)
        for i in range(num_of_options):
            print("press " + str(i + 1) + " to " + options[i])
        try:
            uchoice = int(input("? "))
            if uchoice == 1:
                print("You chose to " + options[uchoice - 1])
                login()
                break
            elif uchoice == 2:
                print("You chose to " + options[uchoice - 1])
                register()
                break
            elif (uchoice - 1) > len(options):
                mainError()
        except ValueError:
            mainError()

Menu()
```

In my code, if the user chooses to register for a new account, it runs the 'register()' method. After the user are their username and password in the method, it writes it to a csv file and then calls the login() method. BUT, instead... it somehow runs the Menu() method instead and ignores my login().

In addition, after the end of the register method is reached, it prints an error message that I made with my 'Class Validation(Exception) and 'mainError()' which I don't want it to - I don't understand why it does this as I have not called mainError().

An example of when I run the code and choose to register:

```
Welcome to the quiz
Would you like to login with an existing account or register for a new account?
Please, choose one of the following options
press 1 to Login
press 2 to Register
? 2
You chose to Register
Your username will now be created from your first name and age.
Please enter your first name: Siddharth
Please enter your age: 16
Your username is SID16
Please enter a password for your new account: shamrock
Username: Sid16
Password: shamrock
Error: Please enter a valid input 
Please, choose one of the following options
press 1 to Login
press 2 to Register
?
```

As you can see, it goes to the Manu() instead of login() after the registration and before it, prints "Error: Please enter a valid input" when there is no need.

How can I fix this. Thank you!

Comment: your code should give a syntax error cuz of `time.sleep(1.0)`

Comment: `f.write(username) in file[0]` doesn't do what you probably think it does.

Comment: does it throw the error immediately after it prints `Password: shamrock` or it throws after you press the `<ENTER>` key?

Comment: it throws the error immediately after it prints Password: shamrock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
with open("UserPass.csv", "w") as f:
    for line in f:
        file = line.split(",")
        f.write(username) in file[0]
```

to

```
with open('UserPass.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write('whatever text you want to save')
```

Comment: And it now works... thank you so much. I'm learning to code so that's why I'm making these stupid mistakes... thanks :)

Comment: @SiddharthChaudhary worry not, everybody learns :) , you can upvote this solution mark this as an answer if your question is solved :)